# What's the value stored in the argument variable when scanf(fscanf) encounters EOF?

Tags: c, eof, scanf

```
int *ptr = malloc~
while (fscanf(fp, "%d", ptr++) != EOF)
    ;
```

Assuming that there's sufficient memory allocated to ptr,
What does the value stored in *ptr when the function encouters EOF indicate?
I tried using debugging tools in Visual Studio and found out that the value of *ptr is -33686019
Is this garbage value? or EOF?

Comment: Uninitialized value, that is garbage value. Also, it is necessary to save the first address.

Comment: Unspecified. EOF is only returned if an error occurred before **the first** input argument was assigned.

Comment: If, for example, the first character in the file was not a digit, then why would [`scanf` (or its siblings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)) store *anything*? If you get `EOF` (or zero!) then you simply can't assume there is a valid value stored.

Comment: By the way, when you use `ptr++` as argument, remember that you lose the original pointer. After you do `ptr++` you can no longer call `free` passing `ptr`, and the position where eventual data is stored is lost.

Comment: Note that if there's a non-digit, non-white-space character in the input (e.g. a letter), then your loop will crash out of control.  You should always condition the loop on the expected number of valid values: `while (fscanf(fp, "%d", ptr++) == 1 && ptr < end) ;` (where `end` is the value assigned originally `ptr` plus the number of `int` allocated).  You also need to preserve the value of `ptr` for use later — for `free()` if nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When scanf hits EOF, **no value is stored** at the address `ptr` points to.
Likewise if it returns 0. This is why the canonical way to iterate over input must check the scanf return value, e.g. with

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &ptr_to_int) == 1) {
  /* successful conversion */
}
else {
  /* Unsuccesful conversion or EOF; use feof() to test which. */
}
```